# Issue while getting SonarQube to work in MacOS

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, sonarqube

I have struggled to get SonarQube to work in my MacOS development machine.
I have followed this tutorial up to the point when the server is supposed to run.

https://mobiosolutions.com/install-sonarqube-installation-guide-mac-os/

I am getting this output:

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2019.09.21 11:31:38 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /Applications/SonarQube/temp
jvm 1    | 2019.09.21 11:31:38 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2019.09.21 11:31:38 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/Applications/SonarQube/elasticsearch]: /Applications/SonarQube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2019.09.21 11:31:38 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
jvm 1    | 2019.09.21 11:31:38 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2019.09.21 11:31:38 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2019.09.21 11:31:47 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2019.09.21 11:31:47 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.09.21 11:31:47 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

So I checked the log and got this error.

```
1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.jdk.internal.vm.annotation")
at _unknown_

1 error
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:361) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.initializeStatically(InjectorBuilder.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:605) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:266) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.jdk.internal.vm.annotation")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1036) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:408) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1324) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:174) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:416) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:440) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:242) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:121) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:73) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:614) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.declaredAnnotations(Executable.java:612) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getAnnotation(Executable.java:582) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Method.java:696) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:87) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:78) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:233) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:96) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:142) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:89) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:605) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:266) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar:6.8.0]
```

The message is truncated but it seems to be a problem with the elastic search permissions, it being run as root.

I tried some solutions but can't get it to work. Even created a new user, changed the permissions of the folder and run it as that user and got the same error.

I am running MacOS High Sierra and Java version is openjdk 13 2019-09-17

Any help will be appreciated!

Excuse my English.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot run elastic search as root. See the [Prerequisites](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements) and see [this](https://michalwegrzyn.wordpress.com/2016/07/14/do-not-run-sonar-as-root/) post.

Comment: I have already tried to run it as a different user without luck. I am moving away from mac for a few days until I solve this. Will work in ubuntu in the meantime

Comment: Meet the same problem on my macbook, have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems SonarQube actually does NOT support Java above version 11:
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/upgrade-path-6-7-3-to-7-9-1/14199/6

Comment: Thank you! that was it, I downgrade to java 11, reinstaled everything from the ground, and it works like a charm.

Comment: now sonarqube supports Java 17 https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/prerequisites-and-overview/